# How to show "No result found" in Mat-select-autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, mat-select

I have used mat-select-autocomplete for multiselect dropdown. If i search some other values, I need to show "No result found". How can i acheive this?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-autocomplete-bjln34?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible with the current API of the package. As you can see in the documentation and in the [implementation](https://github.com/malothnaresh/mat-select-autocomplete/blob/1d56fd21bd86bfad598f59f6d8d2c28553e3dbac/projects/select-autocomplete/src/lib/select-autocomplete.component.ts) you only have one output event that is triggered when an option is toggled.

```
@Output()
selectionChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

For what you want to be possible, the method `filterItem()` method should also be an output and than you could use a `ngIf` to toggle a label.